# Inconsistent commentCount retrieving linkedin darkpost metrics

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm retrieving some linkedin's darkposts metrics through the `organizationalEntityShareStatistics` API. However there are some posts which the API returns me an incorrect number of comments. For example the post has 7 comments and the API returns `commentsCount: 0`.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics#share-statistics-data-schema) states that `likesCount` can contain incorrect values and even negative values. But why it happens with `commentsCount` and with such a big discrepance between reality?